# iOS - Override static home screen quick actions with dynamic actions

Tags: ios, swift, homescreen, quickaction

I have the following requirement. Before user lands on a certain screen I need to configure home screen quick actions say A,B and C for example. Once user lands on a specific screen (or performs a particular action within the app), I need to update the home screen quick actions to have X,Y and Z for example. Is there a way to change from a static list of options to dynamic?
Edit:
This is the official apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/menus_and_shortcuts/add_home_screen_quick_actions